# Using a subquery with inner join in the from clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery

I'm trying to create a table that with one column containing the number of countries and the next column being the number of official countries. So basically, one row might say there are 32 countries that have 2 official languages, 28 with 3 official languages, etc.

So far I've made a table that counts the number of official languages per each individual country.

```
select c.name, count(l.language) number_of_languages from world.country c 
inner join (select countrycode, language, isofficial from
world.countrylanguage where isofficial='T') l on c.code=l.countrycode group
by c.name order by count(l.language)
```

Here's a sample of the result:

```
NAME                                                 NUMBER_OF_LANGUAGES
---------------------------------------------------- -------------------
Lesotho                                                                2
Sri Lanka                                                              2
Canada                                                                 2
Singapore                                                              3
Belgium                                                                3
Bolivia                                                                3
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Didn't get it. Explain what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, your query can be simplified.  It doesn't need to use a subquery:

```
select c.name, count(cl.language) as number_of_languages
from world.country c inner join
     world.countrylanguage cl
     on c.code = cl.countrycode
where cl.isofficial = 'T'
group by c.name
order by count(cl.language);
```

Next, use this as a subquery:

```
select number_of_languages, count(*)
from (select c.name, count(cl.language) as number_of_languages
      from world.country c inner join
           world.countrylanguage cl
           on c.code = cl.countrycode
      where cl.isofficial = 'T'
      group by c.name
     ) cl
group by number_of_languages
order by number_of_languages;
```